What is gñânendriyas?
I read from a question:

Yâgñavalkya replied: 'These ten vital breaths (prânas, the senses,
i.e. the five gñânendriyas, and the five karmendriyas), and Âtman
as the eleventh. When they depart from this mortal body, they make us
cry (rodayanti), and because they make us cry, they are called
Rudras.'

I am looking for clarification. Is gñânendriyas the five bases of power, or the five bases of knowledge, or the five faculties? Which sheath (kosha) according to TAITTIRIYA-UPANISHAD does it belong to? Are there any other texts that use the term?

ज्ञानेन्द्रिय (Jnanendriya / Gyanendriya /
Jñānendriya) are the five knowledge-acquiring organs: the ears, the skin, the eyes, the tongue and the nostrils.
कर्मेन्द्रिय (Karmendriya) are the five organs of action: the mouth, the hands, the legs, the genitalia and the rectum.

…The 'five sensorial organs' are ear, skin, eye, tongue and nose. The ‘five motor organs’ are speech, hands, feet, and the organs of excretion and reproduction. These are the ten senses… ~ Bhagavad Gita 13.6 - English Translation of Ramanuja's Sanskrit Commentary By Swami Adidevananda


soul departs the body.

do u mean jivatman?

yes, souls means atman/jivatman
